# Different layouts on listview VS firebase constant updating

Tags: android, listview, layout, firebase, chat

I'm trying to make a chat app out of a FireBase sample. I want to make it that when the same user sends a message twice there is no header on the second message. I made it so the header's size is 0dp if current user is the same as the last user, but when I scroll or even hide the keyboard the listview updates and messes it up (all headers dissappear). Can I make it check the element above or is there another way?

```
public class ChatListAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<Chat> {

// The mUsername for this client. We use this to indicate which messages originated from this user
private String mUsername;
private Typeface Consolas;
private String lastUsername = "";

public ChatListAdapter(Query ref, Activity activity, int layout, String mUsername) {
    super(ref, Chat.class, layout, activity);
    this.mUsername = mUsername;
    this.Consolas = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/Consolas.ttf");
}

/**
 * Bind an instance of the <code>Chat</code> class to our view. This method is called by <code>FirebaseListAdapter</code>
 * when there is a data change, and we are given an instance of a View that corresponds to the layout that we passed
 * to the constructor, as well as a single <code>Chat</code> instance that represents the current data to bind.
 *
 * @param view A view instance corresponding to the layout we passed to the constructor.
 * @param chat An instance representing the current state of a chat message
 */
@Override
protected void populateView(View view, Chat chat) {
    // Map a Chat object to an entry in our listview
    String author = chat.getAuthor();
    if (!author.equals(lastUsername)) {
        TextView authorText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.author);
        authorText.setText(author);
        // If the message was sent by this user, color it differently
        if (author != null && author.equals(mUsername)) {
            authorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            authorText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#e4de33"));
        }
        authorText.setTypeface(Consolas);
        TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        message.setText(chat.getMessage());
        message.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        message.setTypeface(Consolas);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setText(chat.getDate());
        date.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        date.setTypeface(Consolas);
        lastUsername = mUsername;
    } else {
        view.findViewById(R.id.divider).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        view.findViewById(R.id.header).setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 0));
        TextView message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        message.setText(chat.getMessage());
        message.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        message.setTypeface(Consolas);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_darkblue"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_size"
        android:padding="@dimen/avatar_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/g"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/avatar_padding"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/avatar_padding"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/avatar_padding" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I fixed it by doing this:

```
    String author = chat.getAuthor();
    String previousAuthor = "";
    int currentIndex = getmModels().indexOf(chat);
    if (currentIndex > 0) {
        Chat previousObject = (Chat) getItem(currentIndex - 1);
        previousAuthor = previousObject.getAuthor();
    }
```

And in the parent class I just had to create a getter for mModels. There was also another bug in this code with the layout changes because the adapter reused my changed params. The solution is to change params in both circumstances (same author and different author).

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that `populateView()` is called for each chat message in order. That is not necessarily the case, so you should come up with another way to find if the previous message is from the same user.

The `FirebaseListAdapter.populateView()` method now takes an extra parameter `int position`. With this parameter you an explicitly check whether the message before the current one is by the same user:

```
protected void populateView(View view, Chat chat, int position) {
    String author = chat.getAuthor();
    String previousAuthor = (position > 0) ? getItem(position-1).getAuthor();
    if (!author.equals(previousAuthor)) {
        ...
```